# How to return an array and access that array in python?

Tags: python, arrays

I am getting an error while trying to access the variable inside of the data type defined me.

My data type (class) is foo_type which will contain value in it.

```
def return_array:
    array = []
    i = 0;
    while i<10:
        arr = get_array() # it will return an array of type foo_type
        array.append(arr)
        i = i + 1
    return array

temp_array = return_array()
for arr in temp_array:
    print 'arr.value',arr.value
```

Getting error:

```
list has no type value
```

Comment: What do you expect `arr.value` to be?

Comment: what is the code for `get_array()` ?

Comment: Just write `print 'arr.value', arr`

Comment: Your code gives `InvalidSyntax` exception. Please, provide [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Python has lists and tuples. Try a basic Python tutorial.

Comment: "array of type foo_type" has no meaning in Python. You need to show the code for `get_array`.

Comment: foo_type is defined by me. which has a member called value in it

Comment: What is `get_array()` .and what does it return. Showing us its code would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found couple of mistakes: 
1. def return_array statement wrong. missing "()" 
2. print statement incorrect. 
     no need to call *arr.value* 
     can be called as *arr*.

```
def return_array():
    array = []
    i = 0;
    while i<10:
        arr = get_array() # it will return an array of type foo_type
        array.append(arr)
        i = i + 1
    return array
temp_array = return_array()
for arr in temp_array:
    print 'arr.value' , arr
```

Comment: Why don't you indent your code properly, rather than writing all that about it not being correct?

Comment: I am sorry about that. This is my first reply on this site.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to give the braces to the function. But why I am getting that error. foo_type has a lot of members in it. In that value is one member

Comment: can you show the code for get_array() and also foo_type?